# JS script fails to run in HTML when using fetch()

Tags: javascript, html, express

I'd like to run a script in HTML where it generates some HTML elements based on the response I get from an API call and inserts them into the innerHTML of a div. The problem is that when I run the script by itself and console.log() the result, I can see that the HTML elements are successfully generated. but when I try to run the script in HTML it fails to edit the structure. Here's the script:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
fetch('http://localhost:5000/sampleRoute/sampleParameter')
    .then(function(res){
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        let resultList = createResultList(data);
        //console.log(resultList);
        document.getElementById('sampleID').innerHTML = resultList;
    });
```

The HTML:

```
    <div id="sampleID"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sampleScript.js"></script>
```

Here's what happens if I run the script in isolation and console.log resultList

```
            <div>
                <p>BayID: 2495</p>
                <h4>Distance: 221.4507100415552</h4>
                <h4>Parking Type + Disability Ext: 1P Meter</h4>
                <p>Disability Extension: 120</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>BayID: 2497</p>
                <h4>Distance: 228.83722816851767</h4>
                <h4>Parking Type + Disability Ext: 1P Meter</h4>
                <p>Disability Extension: 120</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>BayID: 2501</p>
                <h4>Distance: 239.1268407711393</h4>
                <h4>Parking Type + Disability Ext: 1P Meter</h4>
                <p>Disability Extension: 120</p>
            </div>
```

So the list is successfully generated but when I try to replace the innerHTML  with the said list it doesn't work. I've also noticed that trying to replace the innerHTML outside of the fetch block works perfectly fine, so perhaps there's something wrong with fetch itself?

**EDIT:** Here's the createResultList function since someone asked for it

```
function createResultList(data) {
    let output = '';
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        output += createResultItem(item);
    });
    return output;
}

function createResultItem(item){
    let columnNum = chooseColumn(item);
    let features = generateFeatures(item, columnNum);

    let result = `
            <div>
                <p>BayID: ${item.spot.BayID}</p>
                <h4>Distance: ${item.distance_to_target}</h4>
                <h4>Parking Type + Disability Ext: ${features.TypeDesc}</h4>
                <p>Disability Extension: ${features.DisabilityExt}</p>
            </div>`;
    return result;
}
```

All it does is return some HTML using the array of json returned from the API call

Comment: Please post your code of createResultList(data);

Comment: I don't think `node-fetch` is meant to be used in the browser. Maybe you want `isomorphic-fetch`. But if you're running in latest browsers, you won't need any library. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is available in the browser itself.

Comment: I tried removing the node-fetch requirement and the HTML still won't load the output

Comment: can you use [https://github.com/github/fetch] from https://flaviocopes.com/fetch-api/ this runs on the browser